# Parsing chat messages as config

Tags: python

I'm trying write a function that would be able to parse out a file with defined messages for a set of replies but am at loss on how to do so.

For example the config file would look:

```
[Message 1]
1: Hey
   How are you?
2: Good, today is a good day.
3: What do you have planned?
   Anything special?
4: I am busy working, so nothing in particular.
   My calendar is full.
```

Each new line without a number preceding it is considered part of the reply, just another message in the conversation without waiting for a response.

Thanks

Edit: The config file will contain multiple messages and I would like to have the ability to randomly select from them all. Maybe store each reply from a conversation as a list, then the replies with extra messages can carry the newline then just split them by the newline. I'm not really sure what would be the best operation.

**Update:**

I've got for the most part this coded up so far:

```
def parseMessages(filename):
  messages = {}
  begin_message = lambda x: re.match(r'^(\d)\: (.+)', x)
  with open(filename) as f:
    for line in f:
      m = re.match(r'^\[(.+)\]$', line)
      if m:
        index = m.group(1)
      elif begin_message(line):
        begin = begin_message(line).group(2)
      else:
        cont = line.strip()
    else:
      # ??
  return messages
```

But now I am stuck on being able to store them into the dict the way I'd like..

How would I get this to store a dict like:

```
{'Message 1': 
  {'1': 'How are you?\nHow are you?', 
   '2': 'Good, today is a good day.', 
   '3': 'What do you have planned?\nAnything special?', 
   '4': 'I am busy working, so nothing in particular.\nMy calendar is full'
  }  
}
```

Or if anyone has a better idea, I'm open for suggestions.

Once again, thanks.

**Update Two**

Here is my final code:

```
import re
def parseMessages(filename):
  all_messages = {}
  num = None
  begin_message = lambda x: re.match(r'^(\d)\: (.+)', x)
  with open(filename) as f:
    messages = {}
    message = []
    for line in f:
      m = re.match(r'^\[(.+)\]$', line)
      if m:
        index = m.group(1)
      elif begin_message(line):
        if num:
          messages.update({num: '\n'.join(message)})
        all_messages.update({index: messages})
        del message[:]
        num = int(begin_message(line).group(1))
        begin = begin_message(line).group(2)
        message.append(begin)
      else:
        cont = line.strip()
        if cont:
          message.append(cont)
    return all_messages
```

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't sound too difficult. Almost-Python pseudocode:

```
for line in configFile:
    strip comments from line
    if line looks like a section separator:
        section = matched section
    elsif line looks like the beginning of a reply:
        append line to replies[section]
    else:
        append line to last reply in replies[section][-1]
```

You may want to use the `re` module for the "looks like" operation. :)

Comment: Gotcha. I will try and code something up using your psuedocode as a guide. I had something in mind that would follow through as you suggested.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a relatively small number of strings, why not just supply them as string literals in a `dict`?

```
{'How are you?' : 'Good, today is a good day.'}
```